# jQuery Ui sortable can`t drag li elements in cloned ul

Tags: jquery, clone, jquery-ui-sortable

i have a problem with a jQuery sortable list. I got two ul-lists. These two lists are sortable (the complete ul-sets) and the li children are sortable also. So you can sort the complete list position and you can sort the li-positions and drag li-elements from one list to another.

Using a button next to each list, i can clone a complete ul-list. Therefore i use the clone(true,true) function. I use true parameters, because i got events on the buttons and i want them to be applied to the clones. I also want the sortable function to be applied to the clone.

Problems:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**When i only use `clone()` to clone the element:**

You cant drag the li Elements from the ul>-clone to another list and
   you can`t clone a cloned element twice with the clone-button (button
   action got lost).

**When i use `clone(true)` or `clone(true,true)` to clone the element:**

You can drag li-elements from the ul-clone to another list, but you can`t drag li-elements from other lists to the ul-clone.

You can try it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uKEJL/133/

Any Idea?

-Thx Tobi-

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has to do with bindings. The event callbacks get bound to the current widget object. Compare

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js#L31-L41

If you clone the lists, the event gets fired correctly by jQuery, but the callback is bound to the original list.

You will have to initialize sortable on every clone.

Comment: Hi, and how is it possible to bind the sortable functions directly to each clone? I looked at the mouse code on your linked page, but Iàm not shure, how to transfer this to the clone?

Comment: just call clone.sortable(options), as I stated. Transfering events to the clone will not work. You have to create new events.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but when i use sortable on the clone like:  cloneHdl.sortable({
            connectWith: ".sconnect"
        }).disableSelection();  
it is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/6fsWh/17/

Comment: It works. You were calling it on the wrong part of the clone http://jsfiddle.net/weqYs/