# Inconsistent Sorting: Using jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

We have hierarchical items here with a series of TR structure and not in a nested table structure. So we need to have the functionality to drag and drop items with the same level or a function to sort same level items.

For example I'll try to move Item 1.1 below Item 1.4, that row must be displayed below Item 1.4 together with its children items(Item 1.1.1 and Item 1.1.2). It will work but if you will try to move the children items, it will not work.

And we should also be able to sort/move the Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3 together with its children.

Help with regards to these sorting in jQuery UI.

```
var tmpTr = jQuery(ui.item).clone(true, true);

var tmpParent = jQuery('tbody[data="'+ui.item[0].id+'"]').clone(true,true);
```

I think there's something wrong in my code for clone. By the way here's the jsFiddle link

[http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/403/ ]

Thanks,

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497383/jquery-ui-sortable-cant-drag-li-elements-in-cloned-ul/15507978

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with jquery-ui Sortable for a recent implementation of a heirarchical list of items that are draggable/droppable/sortable, I ended up rolling my own implementation using Draggable and Droppable.  It helped avoid a lot of squidgy issues with hierarchical and complex sorting/dragging/dropping interactions with Sortable.  Even though I got less up front, I was able handle all the cases we needed to without understanding and hacking the default behavior of Sortable. This is not exactly an answer to your question about the behavior of clone, but it may help!